# Не могу отцентрировать блок, подскажите как правильно центрировать

Tags: html, css, flexbox, position, центрирование

Пытаюсь центрировать и через `flex`, и через `grid`, он начинает ездить. А если использую `position: absolute`, то он просто пропадает. Не обращайте внимания на блок, я его не заполнял контентом потому что не могу его отцентрировать.
[image: Проблема]
[image: Как должно быть]

```css
.review {
    height: 950px;
    background-color: #F2EBDC;
    font-family: 'Roboto';
}

h1 {
    font-size: 48px;
    color: #594740;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin-top: -90px;
}

.first-review__line {
    background-color: #8F9471;
    width: 100%;
    height: 35px;
    top: 120px;
    position: relative;
}

.second-review__line {
    background-color: #8F9471;
    width: 100%;
    height: 95px;
    top: 780px;
    position: relative;
}

.review__container {
}

.review__slider {
    position: relative;
    top: 80px;
}

.review__block {
    margin-left: 250px;
    width: 815px;
    height: 530px;
    background: #8F9471;
    box-shadow: -9px 11px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
```

```html
<section class="review">
    <div class="review__top"></div>
    <div class="first-review__line"></div>
    <div class="second-review__line"></div>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>
            Отзывы клиентов
        </h1>
        <div class="review__container">
            <div class="review__slider">
                <div class="review__block">
                    <div class="review__item">
                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="review__item"></div>
                    <div class="review__item"></div>
                    <div class="review__item"></div>
                    <div class="review__item"></div>
                    <div class="review__item"></div>
                    <div class="review__item"></div>
                    <div class="review__item"></div>
                    <div class="review__item"></div>
                    <div class="review__item"></div>
                    <div class="review__item"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы же в стилях для review__block указали отступ слева как `margin-left: 250px;`
Замените на `margin: 0 auto;`

В этом случае отступы сверху и снизу будут нулевые, а слева и справа - auto, то есть одинаковые автоматические. Блок встанет посередине.